# sed/awk: replace spaces in a substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

How can I use sed or awk to convert this string:

`|    "A rand0m string of charact3rs"           |`

into this:

`|    "A_rand0m_string_of_charact3rs"           |`

i.e. to substitute underscores for spaces only inside the quotes?

The number of words in the string is unknown.

I managed:

`echo "|    \"A rand0m string of charact3rs\"           |" | awk ' BEGIN {FS="\""} {gsub(/ /,"_",$2); for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf $i "\""; print $NF} '`

but what if he string contains multiple quoted fragments?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Command with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
echo '|    "A rand0m string of charact3rs"           |' |
    perl -pe 's/(\w+)\s+/${1}_/g'
```

Or with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
... | sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]]+)\s+/\1_/g'
```

## Result

```
|    "A_rand0m_string_of_charact3rs"
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Gilles Quenot. Your sed works like a charm with any number of quoted fragments!